# jquery preloaded imgages with rollovers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rollover

So I am doing something very basic that can be done with CSS but I want to do it with jQuery to get familiar with the library.

I am trying to create a rollover image gallery. Where when you put the mouse over the image it will be swapped with a slightly edited version of it.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery</title>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/one_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/two_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/three_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/four_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/five_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/six_s.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var alternate = ['images/one_s_edited.jpg',
                    'images/two_s_edited.jpg',
                    'images/three_s_edited.jpg',
                    'images/four_s_edited.jpg',
                    'images/five_s_edited.jpg',
                    'images/six_s_edited.jpg'];

    var $selection = $("#gallery img");

    for(var i = 0; i < alternate.length; i++)
    {

        var imgObject = new Image();

        var downloadedImg = imgObject.src = alternate[i];

        console.log(downloadedImg);

        var originalSrc = $selection.eq(i).attr("src");

        console.log(originalSrc + "\n");

        $selection.eq(i).hover(
            function(){
                $(this).attr("src", downloadedImg);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).attr("src", originalSrc);
            }
        );//End hover

    }//End loop
});//End ready
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to the final result: [link](http://spontaneouspeople.com/jquery/jquery.html)

As you can see it rolls over but not as planned. It ends up with the last rollover-image and doesn't change back to the original nor does it show the appropriate rollover image that corresponds with it.

Any simple suggestions without using regular expressions?

Comment: your answer lies within https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: Classic problem with each closure sharing the same variable. About a million duplicates on Stack Overflow. You need to provide each iteration with a unique copy of downloadedImg and originalSrc.

Comment: Thanks for the article @ArunPJohny no I understand the problem 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the wrong usage of a closure variable in a loop.

But the solution can be simplified to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $selection = $("#gallery img");
    $selection.hover(function () {
        this.src = this.src.replace('.jpg', '_edited.jpg')
    }, function () {
        this.src = this.src.replace('_edited.jpg', '.jpg')
    })
}); //End ready
```

Comment: How would I bind this to all the elements in the selection?

Comment: @robertrocha sorry I didn't get you.. what do you want to do?

Comment: How do I bind the event handlers to all the different images when the mouse is rolled over?

Comment: @robertrocha PoC http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k534y/1/ you will still have to handler the preloading code

Comment: Each different image has an alternate image that is swapped, it's the same image but slightly edited. Therefore, I would think that a loop would be required to go through each image and modify the "src" attribute to its own slightly edited image. They don't all have the same rollover image.